# Do I need to compute and analyze my data differently since it was "Convenience" sampled?

Tags: sampling, bias

I've just done a survey of 201 students and some staff at my College. The questionnaire asked respondents mostly about their opinions about the recycling facilities on campus and as well as their recycling attitudes and behaviors. However, the way I sampled was through convenience sampling, where I chose to give questionnaires to people sometimes in the open areas; many times I chose people around sitting areas and some other times in the corridors of the campus. As this is clearly convenience sampling, I would like to ask if there is anything different that I need to do with the data that I have? I ask this as I know so far that with randomly sampled data there is far less bias compared with convenience sampling. But I'm wondering if I need to compute anything into my analysis program in order to account for the sampling error brought about from convenience sampling?
Or is it just sufficient for me to state in my results or discussion section that the results are subject to bias due to convenience sampling?

Comment: When you do convenience sampling there is an unknown potential bias that cannot be accounted for.  You have no way to make inference to the population based on the sample.

Comment: So am I correct in saying that the best I can do is to mention in my methodology section that the reader should interpret the results in light of the fact that my sampling was convenience sampling?

Comment: That would be a very good idea.